# remove post that has no content

Tags: php, posts, loop

Code below display posts now I only want to display the items if it has a `<?php echo c2c_get_custom('Gallery'); ?>` on it.

```
    <ul id="gallery-container">
        <?php 
            global $post;
            $post_slug = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
            $args = array ( 'category_name' => $post_slug, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => title, 'order' => ASC);
            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <li data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php if (c2c_get_custom('Gallery')): ?>
                    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('Gallery'); ?>
                <?php else : 
                    echo '<p style="display:block !important;"></p>'; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

I have this second loop. Is it possible to hide the item in the loop if it has no value on the `<?php echo c2c_get_custom('Gallery'); ?>`? also if it can be bind with the first loop so it is not available in the menu?

```
        <ul id="gallery-container">
            <?php 
                global $post;
                $post_slug = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
                $args = array ( 'category_name' => $post_slug, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => title, 'order' => ASC);
                $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <li data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <?php if (c2c_get_custom('Gallery')): ?>
                        <?php echo c2c_get_custom('Gallery'); ?>
                    <?php else : 
                        echo '<p style="display:block !important;"></p>'; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```